# Eslint nullish coalescing combined with optional chaining problem

Tags: typescript, eslint

Lets say we have these three expressions linted by eslint:

```
const exp1 = a ?? b; // ok
const exp2 = a?.b // ok
const exp3 = a?.b ?? c // Parsing error: ':' expected.
```

All works and are successfully compiled with typescript, but the last expression throws eslint error `Parsing error: ':' expected.` It seems there is problem with combination of Nullish coalescing and optional chaining. Is there someone who met this problem?

package.json

```
"eslint": "5.16.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
"ts-node": "8.5.4",
"typescript": "3.7.4"
```

Comment: have you tried upgrading eslint?

Comment: its my bad, I tried to update it but i forgot to restart VS Code. Dont know why it cant reaload eslint version without restart.